# Delphi ключевое слово uses

Tags: delphi

Доброго времени суток!

Имеем unit1.pas

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses abc;
implementation
end.
```

unit2.pas

```
unit Unit2;
interface
uses abc;
implementation
end.
```

project1.dpr

```
program project1;
uses unit1, unit2, abc;
begin
end.
```

Сколько раз реально будет подключён модуль **abc**?
То есть после компиляции весь код содержащийся в **abc**
в исполняемом файле сколько раз будет скопирован? (или не будет... =) )

Спасибо! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один раз.

Компилятор его скомпилит, и линкер прилинкует к пусковому файлу. А все функции которые в нем объявлены будут доступны по указателям.